# Android custom listview add new item row position

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using custom listview in my android application. It is working fine, the problem I am facing is

When I add a new row, instead of adding the new line in the bottom, it is adding in the top of the list.

Example it is coming like this

3

1

2

3 is the new line added

I am using this code for adding new row

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iCount = lview.getCount()+1; //Serial number in list
        adapter.insert(new Zone("",iCount,0), 0); //for new row the edittext should be blank
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iCount = iCount+1; //Serial number in list
        adapter.insert(new Zone("",iCount,0),  adapter.getCount()); //for new row the edittext should be blank
    }
});
```

What I added is the adapter.getCount(), as you can see the second parameter of the insert method is the position, you're setting it to 0, so it's inserting at the beginning.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T,%20int)

Or you can try:

```
adapter.add(new Zone("",iCount,0) );
```

Comment: I would say isn't last index `getCount() - 1`? In case adapter starts add items from index zero.

Comment: Yes, @Guarav you're right, it will be better if you call the add method, or just be careful with the size of the Array to avoid an OutOfBoundsException, I'll leave it to you Subramanian Raj

Comment: Thanks Guarav and Moxi, I will take care of this issue